# What is the best way saving sorting to sql?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, sorting

I have mysql table with data which I print as html table, with JS and drag&drop I can sort that table localy, then I able to send ajax to server, what the best way to save changes of sorting rows? what should be in ajax request and what sql queryes should I run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have an `order` field in your MySQL table. The values are integers which represent the order of your rows, like this:

```
my_table

| ID |  NAME  | ORDER |
|----|--------|-------|
|  0 |  john  |   2   |
|  1 |  henry |   1   |
|  2 |  suzan |   3   |
```

So everytime you save your data, you update your MySQL field `order` by sending the data with ajax and a `for` loop on your HTML table. In JS, something like:

```
function update()
{
   //get your table
   var table = document.getElementById(my_table);
   //for loop on the table rows
   for(var i=0;i<table.rows.length;i++)
   {
      //get your data id
      var id = rows[i].cells[0];
      //get your order index
      var order = rows[i].cells[1];
      //send in ajax
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
         if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status==200)
         {
            //update confirm message
            alert('update ok');
         }
      }
      xhr.open('POST', 'update.php', true);
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
      xhr.send('id='+id+'&order='+order);
   }
}
```

The MySQL request in your php file called with Ajax should be:

```
<?php

   mysql_query("UPDATE my_table 
                   SET order = '".$_POST['order']."' 
                 WHERE id = '".$_POST['id']."';");

?>
```

Finally, to get your data in the right order with MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY order;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need to send with your ajax request 2 extra variables: column name and sort order like:

```
 ....&col=col2&sort=descending
```

then, in PHP:

```
    $columns = array('col1'=>'column_name_in_table',
'col2'=> 'second_column_name_in_table',
'colx'=> 'column_x_name_in_table',);
$sortorder = array('ascending'=>'asc','descending'=>'desc');

$query .= "ORDER BY ".$columns[$_POST['col']]." ".$sortorder[$_POST['sort']];
```

You would also need additional checks, but at minimum these arrays make sure that this part of your code is SQL injection proof.